# Steganalysis tool to detect steganography in audio/video?

Tags: audio, video, steganography

After having developed a steganography tool for hiding information in audio and video files using the Least Significant Bit Approach and EOF Byte stuffing, I was looking for software which can detect steganography in those files (WAV, MP3, FLAV ,AVI), to assess the performance of my software. I came accross StegoWatch which detect steganography but it is a paid software. Are there any free tools which can detect steganography for the above listed formats?

Comment: Questions asking to recommend a software are [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I am not looking only for a software. Any algorithm to perform the task is welcome.

Comment: There are many steganalysis algorithms which can detect lsb embedding. Lsb embedding itself can have many variants, such as trying to embed the information in noisy areas, random embedding, attempts to conserve statitical features of the cover medium, etc. Each steganographic algorithm is designed with its strengths and weaknesses. You haven't provided enough information to restrict the criteria here. And there are more than one steganalysis algorithms that can detect just a single steganographic algorithm. See [closed questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) reasons.

Comment: Have you even reviewed the literature to see what available algorithms there are? You question still sounds like a recommendation question due to lack of research effort.